# Ошибка возникающая при переносе на сервер

Tags: java, rmi

Добрый день.
Есть самописный чат-сервер на java и админка под tomcat, взаимодействующие через jmx.

При запуске на локальной машине все работает, кроме jmx подключения (на отрез отказывается подключаться к удаленному серверу).

При запуске на сервере, в логе начинают появляться ошибки формата

```
PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.ModelData com.mychat.admin.client.services.ServerService.getServerInfo()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge
```

Я догадываюсь, что проблема в настройках или дистрибутивах на сервере, но понять в чем именно причина я не могу уже порядка недели.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь использовать `com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge` (клиентская часть) на стороне сервера. Клиентские классы GWT должны использоваться только для генерации JavaScript-кода, на этапе сборки приложения, но не во время выполнения приложения (Runtime).

Попробуйте заменить импорт `com.google.gwt.core.client.GWTBridge` на `com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWTBridge`.

Comment: Это бесспорно логично, и я сумел нагуглить это решение... проблема в том, что этот класс не вызывается в моем коде, видимо вызовы при компиляции получаются...

Answer (score 0):

Так или иначе, проблема решена путем обновления tomcat до 8ой версии. Для меня суть проблемы осталась мистикой.